# converting anonymous types to list in C#

Tags: c#, anonymous

I am trying to convert anonymous types to list but i am getting invocation errors like below.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
var all = from a in Fcticuclist
          join b in crlist on a.Ref_CID equals b.C_ID
          select new { b.MU_Identifier, a.Status,a.ID };

foreach (var item in all)
{
    castapprove.Add(new muapprovelist { Id = item.ID, MU_Identifier = item.MU_Identifier, Status = item.Status });
}
```

so here "all" is anonymous type and  castapprove is a list and muapprovelist is a class and they are declared in the same view model. Any pointers where i am doing it wrong ?

Comment: how is `castapprove` *declared*? what kind of list is it? are you perhaps using `dynamic`? My *guess* here is that you have `dynamic castapprove = ...` in which case... yeah, I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: The `TargetInvocationException` normally has an `InnerException` that explains what _really_ went wrong (and _where_). Please post that information, too. Is  `muapprovelist` the correct type for elements in that list (because it sounds like a list itself)?

Comment: Shouldn't `new { b.MU_Identifier, a.Status,a.ID }` be `new{MU_Identifier = b.MU_Identifier, Status = aStatus , ID = a.Status,a.ID }`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled that's no problem, you don't need to specify names, the compiler takes the names of the properties you give (`MU_Identifier`, `Status` and `ID` in this case).

Comment: @RenéVogt Thanks, I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: @MarcGravell castapprove is declared like this "public List<muapprovelist> castapprove { get; set; }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably this is some accessibility issue relating to dynamic compilation of a view of some kind and the anonymous type (which is `internal`). Perhaps a pragmatic solution is to not use the anonymous type in this case:

```
var all = from a in Fcticuclist
      join b in crlist on a.Ref_CID equals b.C_ID
      select new muapprovelist {
          Id = a.ID, MU_Identifier = b.MU_Identifier,
          Status = a.Status };

foreach (var item in all)
{
    castapprove.Add(item);
}
```

Perhaps even:

```
var castapprove = (from a in Fcticuclist
      join b in crlist on a.Ref_CID equals b.C_ID
      select new muapprovelist {
          Id = a.ID, MU_Identifier = b.MU_Identifier,
          Status = a.Status }).ToList();
```

Alternatively: move this code away from the view area into code that is part of the main pre-compiled assembly.

Comment: I tried the second solution and it worked, Thank you so much. That was a good learning for me.